# Machine Learning implementation for predicting number plate checksum

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a dataset of number plates in a format:

```
LLNNNNC
```

Where L is a letter, N is a number and C is the checksum (a letter generated from the six characters before it).

e.g.

```
ET6666A
SM1111M
LG0080P
EU5555M
EQ0823T
KT0094T
KQ0050K
```

There is a deterministic way of finding the checksum (using the checksum algorithm), but I need to find a feasible non-deterministic way of doing it.

Using scikit-learn, I've tried various classifiers such as RidgeClassifier, Nearest Neighbours, SVC, MLPClassifier etc., but none gave me a good enough accuracy (almost all of the accuracies were below 0.1).

Both the letters and the checksum were encoded using LabelEncoder, and any missing/null values were removed. So there isn't any problem with a bad dataset.

I'm starting to think that there might not be any feasible way of implementing this, and would like to hear what the experienced folks here think.